# Selectively hiding subviews in swiftui

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-tabview

TabView accepts a `content` body that contains multiple subviews, and displays only one of them at a time.

I would like to make my own view that receives heterogeneous Content via a viewBuilder, the same way, and then selectively displays only one of the child views so provided, hiding the rest.

Something **like what TabView does**, but under my programmatic control, and **without** TabView's other behaviors. It should be able to accept content items of any mix of types, e.g. from a `ForEach` output, `Group` elements, etc. **Just like TabView does**.

What I have:

[image: what I have]

But I want just *one* of those three subviews to be visible (my choice).

Here is the code that I would like to make work, the goal should be clear...

```
import SwiftUI

struct SwitcherView<Content>: View where Content: View {

  let content: () -> Content
  @State var selection: Int = 0 // will be changed by logic not shown

  public init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
    self.content = content
  }

  @MainActor public var body: some View {

    VStack {

      content()[selection] // obviously this doesn't work

    }
  }
}

struct SwitcherView_Previews: PreviewProvider {

  static var previews: some View {
    VStack {
      Text("I would like to show just one of these at a time:")
      SwitcherView {
        // Note heterogeneous content: each element
        // has its own type and state, none of which
        // SwitcherView gets to know about explicitly..
        // just like TabView!

        Text("First Content")
          .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
          .background(.red)

        Button(action: {}, label: {
          Text("I'm a yellow button!")
        })
        .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
        .tint(.green)
        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)

        HStack {
          Text("Some thing").background(.yellow)
          Text("Else").background(.blue)
        }
        .frame(width: 100, height:100)
        .background(.brown)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

TabView does it, so it's clearly possible! (for Apple.)

Approaches that don't work:

- *Privately wrap the content in a custom `Layout`:* `Layout`s can't hide subviews.
- *Receive content as an array of AnyView instead:* horribly un-SwiftUI like to use, and forces use of `AnyView`, which is performance poison
- *List my sub-views explicitly, wrapping each with its show/hide logic:* Bad encapsulation. Not the desired API.

Comment: How about this: use an array of colored square views and replace the views you don't want with an `EmptyView`.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: I did not! the only answer recommends a pattern I am specifically trying to avoid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR; This can be implemented with result builders or variadic views. The latter has better (not yet perfect) support for ForEach and Group, but uses an 'undocumented' interface.

## First Approach

This is possible with the help of a Result Builder, TabViews are implemented using a similar technique. Note that you will need separate buildBlock functions and internal views for different amounts of subviews. This is the reason the number of subviews in SwiftUI is limited to 10! You can probably use the new Swift Macro's to prevent you from hand-coding this (but I consider this to be beyond the scope of this answer).

I am going to use a custom environment variable to control which view is shown.

```
private struct SelectedIndexKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue: Int = 0
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var selectedIndex: Int {
        get { self[SelectedIndexKey.self] }
        set { self[SelectedIndexKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}
```

The code for the result builder:

```
struct SwitcherInternal3<V0: View, V1: View, V2: View>: View {
    @Environment(\.selectedIndex) private var selectedIndex
    
    let v0: V0
    let v1: V1
    let v2: V2
    
    var body: some View {
        switch(selectedIndex) {
        case 0:
            v0
        case 1:
            v1
        case 2:
            v2
        default:
            EmptyView()
        }
    }
}
    
@resultBuilder
enum SwitcherBuilder {
    static func buildBlock<V0: View, V1: View, V2: View>(
        _ v0: V0,
        _ v1: V1,
        _ v2: V2) -> some View {
        SwitcherInternal3(v0: v0, v1: v1, v2: v2)
    }
}
```

The implementation of the SwitcherView:

```
struct SwitcherView<Content>: View where Content : View {
    let selectedIndex: Int
    let content: Content
    
    public init(_ selectedIndex: Int, @SwitcherBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.selectedIndex = selectedIndex
        self.content = content()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        content
            .environment(\.selectedIndex, selectedIndex)
    }
}
```

And how to use the SwitcherView:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selectedIndex = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        SwitcherView(selectedIndex) {
            Text("First Content")
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .background(.red)

            Button(action: {}, label: {
                Text("I'm a yellow button!")
            })
                .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                .tint(.green)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)

            HStack {
                Text("Some thing").background(.yellow)
                Text("Else").background(.blue)
            }
                .frame(width: 100, height:100)
                .background(.brown)
        }
        
        Button(action: { selectedIndex = (selectedIndex + 1) % 3 }) {
            Text("Select View")
        }
    }
}
```

## Second Approach

This approach uses variadic views https://movingparts.io/variadic-views-in-swiftui, which allows us to access child views. Since this uses an interface prefixed with an underscore, I would not use it in production. The code is a lot simpler, since we do not need a custom resultBuilder and just use the viewBuilder.

```
struct SwitcherView<Content: View>: View {
    
    let selectedIndex: Int
    let content: Content

    init(_ selectedIndex: Int, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.selectedIndex = selectedIndex
        self.content = content()
    }

    var body: some View {
        _VariadicView.Tree(SwitchedLayout(selectedIndex)) { content }
    }
}

struct SwitchedLayout: _VariadicView_MultiViewRoot {
    
    let selectedIndex: Int
    
    init(_ selectedIndex: Int) {
        self.selectedIndex = selectedIndex
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func body(children: _VariadicView.Children) -> some View {
        if selectedIndex < children.count {
            children[selectedIndex]
        } else {
            EmptyView()
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** This approach still does not support mixing ForEach and other content! ForEach on its own works fine.

Comment: Nice! Interesting approach, and the closest anyone's come yet. Unfortunately ForEach and Group would confuse it - the ForEach or Group would be a single "tab", rather than its contents being available to switch over - but this works if the switched content is statically known and "flat". I'll give it a day or two for other approaches, but you're in the lead

Comment: @rgeorge [link](https://movingparts.io/variadic-views-in-swiftui) details an approach that may solve the usage of ForEach and Group. The downside is that it uses structures prefixed with an underscore: I would probably not use it in production code. I'll try to add this second appoarch to the answer.

Comment: That was a fascinating read! I think _VariadicView, despite being quasi-private, is the true answer to the fundamental problem. The way ViewModifiers distribute over children hints at the possibility of a non-private solution I might play around with a bit… but You Win with this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to selectively hide a subview, one approach is to use a parent view that holds an array and current selection. With this information, you can choose which subview to show from the array.

To demonstrate this, I've created a Model struct that holds a `word` and a `color`.

```
struct Model {
    let word: String
    let color: Color
}
```

The parent view, has an array of a `model` and a `selection state variable`, which represents the index of the currently selected array.

The `SwitcherView` is a generic view that takes a selection binding and a closure that returns the content to be shown. In this case, the content is a colored square with the selected word.

Overall, this approach allows us to selectively show a subview by changing the selection state variable.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let data: [Model] = [.init(word: "the",
                               color: .red), 
                         .init(word: "cow", 
                               color: .yellow),
                         .init(word: "say", 
                               color: .green),
                         .init(word: "moo", 
                               color: .blue)]
    
    @State var selection: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        SwitcherView(selection: $selection) {
            Text(data[selection].word)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .background(data[selection].color)
            
        }
    }
}

struct SwitcherView<Content>: View where Content: View {
    let content: () -> Content
    @Binding var selection: Int
    
    public init(selection: Binding<Int>,
                @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self._selection = selection
        self.content = content
    }
    
    @MainActor public var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("I would like to pick out just #\(selection) of these:")
            content()
            Text("But here they all are...")
            Button {
                selection = (selection + 1) % 4
            } label: {
                Text("next")
            }.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent).padding()
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

One area for improvement in this code is the hard-coded value of 4 used to represent the size of the array. If the size of the array were to change, this could lead to a memory leak.

To address this, it's recommended to use the actual size of the array instead of a hard-coded value. This can be achieved by passing the count property of the array to the subview or by using a constant that's updated whenever the array changes size.

By doing so, the subview will always have the correct size, and you won't have to worry about manually updating the value every time the array changes.

Comment: Nice try! But I need my view to be provided with *heterogeneous* *subviews*, not view models. I'm trying to abstract out the switched views from the switcher completely. I'll update my example to try and make it more clear

Comment: also, hardcoding the array length cannot leak memory, it can only crash the app.